# Recursion for even array in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, recursion

I understand there are a lot of questions around even recursion here, but I don't know in C wether its my logic or my syntax that's wrong (or presumably both) because from what I know I may need pointers. Especially when I'm using function in C, so I can harldy find any question that I can understand as a freshman in cs undergrads.

So my assignment was to simply create an array with even numbers in range determined in input, if input `n = 10`, then the array needs to contain `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`, if `n = 9` then the array would simply be `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`. But I have to do it with recursion and I don't know what's wrong with my code since the output is somewhat weird.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int even(int x, int arrEven[]) {

    if (x == 0) {
        arrEven[0] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x > 0) {    
        arrEven[x - 1] = even(x - 2, arrEven) + 1;
        return arrEven[x - 1];
    }
}

int main(void) {

    printf("n = ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n = (n / 2) + 1;
    int arrEven[n];
    even(n, arrEven);

    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        printf("%d, ", arrEven[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", arrEven[n - 1]);
}
```

When I input `10` the output was

```
0, 1, -731908444, 2, 781232032, 3
```

instead of

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Comment: You are messing up your value `n` as upper limit of your range and as index for your array. You use `n-1` as index to store the current value but call the function with `x-2` for next recursion. That will skip every second element in your array. You must decide if `n` shall be the upper limit or the array index. Both at the same time will not work.

Comment: so I assume I need another form of iterator for indexing through the array and recursion? Can you give some example because I haven't get the grasp yet as to why and how I should do it, thankyou very much in advance for answering and fixing my grammar, this is my first question here in SO and I'm happy to get any help

Comment: Simply work on the index, call *even(n-1,arr)*, the 0 case is ok, then simply do *arr[x]=even(x-1,arr)+2* and *return arr[x]* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive function only initializes half the destination array because in `arrEven[x - 1] = even(x - 2, arrEven) + 1;` you decrement `x` by `2` instead of incrementing the value by `2`. You can fix your code this way:

```
int even(int x, int arrEven[]) {

    if (x == 0) {
        arrEven[0] = 0;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (x > 0) {    
        arrEven[x - 1] = even(x - 1, arrEven) + 2;
        return arrEven[x - 1];
    }
}
```

Note however that the above code does not use tail recursion and will require a stack depth proportional to `x`. Here is an alternative where the recursion only happens just before returning from the function:

```
void even(int n, int arrEven[]) {
    if (n > 0) {
        errEven[n - 1] = 2 * (n - 1);
        even(n - 1, arrEven);
    }
}
```

The above function should compile to similar executable code as the equivalent iterative version:

```
void even(int n, int arrEven[]) {
    while (n > 0) {
        n = n - 1;
        errEven[n] = 2 * n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mix the usage of one variable for two purposes.
In your code, `n` is used as index in the array and as value to be put into the array at the same time.

There are tons of options to do this. One could looke like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void even(int *arrEven, int value, int limit) {

    *arrEven = value;

    if (value < limit) {
        even(arrEven+1, value+2, limit);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    int limit;
    int count;

    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    // TODO: Check return value.
    if (limit < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Only non-negative limits are allowed.\n");
      exit(-1);
    }

    count = (limit / 2) + 1;
    int arrEven[count];

    even(arrEven, 0, limit);

    for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++){
        printf("%d, ", arrEven[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", arrEven[count-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
int even(int x, int arrEven[])
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    arrEven[x - 1] = even(x - 1, arrEven);
    return arrEven[x - 1] + 2;
}
```

Here `x` is purely the array index, and the fact that only even values go into the array is handled by the fact that `2` is added to the value returned by `even` along with the terminal condition returning `0`.

Comment: If user enters `n=0` you do not fill `arrEven[0]`.